# SMS source identification in gateway

Tags: php, sms-gateway

I have built an application which deals with SMS from specific sender's, the SMS is received through SMS gateway into my Machine but i wonder how can i verify that the SMS received is really from trusted network source cos i seen some applications online which send SMS with alphanumeric sender this can confuse the system if care hasn't been taken.

What approaches can be deployed to stay in a safer side so that all the targeted SMS should be verified to be from trusted source.

trusted source: a trusted source should be the phone numbers holder's network or anything relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the SMS system uses GSM network and this is out of your control.  I have years of experience working with SMS and also programmed an old SMS platform. As I know the SMS sender ID could be fake easily, in fact if you have access to low-level GSM network you can send whatever sender id you want (numbers, alphanumieric, etc...)

If you want to make sure a SMS was sent by a real phone number I think the only and 100% secure way is to resend a confirmation SMS to this sender number and wait for the confirmation code. It's rude but is trustable.  That does not mean the sender is a real phone, it could be a virtual number but you cannot do anything to solve that.

As I remember every specific network and provider have special services. For example in Spain I remember we consumed a service which inform us about any phone number, it was throuwing us the company (provider) and the time of the last connection of this number, but it was a paid service (very expensive, more or less 0,10€ for each check).

Anyway, any information depends on the implementation and interface of your API provider.

Here you have GSM 3.4 specification for more information.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.40

Comment: i represented my app to mobile carrier so we are negotiating for possible solutions